# SitecoreSearchContrib - How to merge & sort from multiple indexes

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

I'm currently setting up a search for a Sitecore 6.6 web site using SitecoreSearchContrib.

I've got two indexes.
One index looking at my web site content:

```
/sitecore/content/home
```

and another index looking in a documents folder in the media library (which contains PDF etc).

```
/sitecore/media library/documents
```

The search on my web site can return web pages or Word/PDF documents.

Is there a way (beside using one super-index for content & media library) that I can combine the results from both indexes and still order them by their relevance / hit count?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't or don't want to have both locations under one index?

Comment: @ToddB No mate, that's exactly what I ended up doing a few hours after I posted this question. Wasn't clear that you could do that from the documentation.

Comment: @GFoley83 which document you are referring, as I require that..

Comment: @HarshBaid PDF and Word docs, located in a predetermined folder in the media library. All you need to do is add another `<locations>` section to the `scSearchContrib.Crawler.config` and specify the root path for the section to include in the index.

Comment: I mean that is there any documentation for configuring `SitecoreSearchContrib` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up solving this by getting rid of the second index and instead, simply included an additional `<locations>...</locations>` block in the `scSearchContrib.Crawler.config` to point to the folder in the media library where my documents live.

E.g.

Inside of `App_Config/Include/scSearchContrib.Crawler.config`

```
......
<index id="web" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="folder">web</param>
    <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <my-site-content type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.Crawlers.AdvancedDatabaseCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler">
        <Database>web</Database>
        <Root>/sitecore/content/MySite/Home</Root>
        <tags>Web Content</tags>
        <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>

        <!-- Include/Exclude templates, crawlers etc here -->

    </locations>
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <my-site-media-library type="scSearchContrib.Crawler.Crawlers.AdvancedDatabaseCrawler,scSearchContrib.Crawler">
        <Database>web</Database>
        <Root>/sitecore/media library/SomeFolder/Documents</Root>
        <tags>Documents</tags>
        <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>   

        <!-- Include/Exclude templates, crawlers etc here -->

    </locations>
</index>
......
```